# MongoDB ipv4/ipv6 hex index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am building a ipv4/ipv6 geo ip **MongoDB** database and i will have millions (100+) of ips

Structure will of the database will be

```
[
    { _id: 58fdbf5c0ef8a50b4cdd9a8e , ip: '34.53.63.25', ip_hex: '0x22353f19' , type: "ipv4", data : [
        {
            country : "CA",
            region : "region1"
            city : "city1",
            blacklisted : "no"
            on_date : ISODate("2022-05-05T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            country : "CA",
            region : "region1"
            city : "city1",
            blacklisted : "yes"
            on_date : ISODate("2022-06-05T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            country : "US",
            region : "region2"
            city : "city2",
            blacklisted : "no"
            on_date : ISODate("2022-05-05T00:00:00Z")
        },

        ...
    ]},

    { _id: 58fdbf5c0ef8a50b4cdd9a8e , ip: '1.2.3.4', ip_hex: '0x1020304', type: "ipv4", data : [
        {
            country : "CA",
            region : "region1"
            city : "city1",
            blacklisted : "no"
            on_date : ISODate("2022-06-05T00:00:00Z")
        },
    ]},


    { _id: 58fdbf5c0ef8a50b4cdd9a8e , ip: '2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5', ip_hex: '0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5', type: "ipv6", data : [
        {
            country : "FR",
            region : "region1"
            city : "city1",
            blacklisted : "no"
            on_date : ISODate("2022-06-05T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            country : "FR",
            region : "region1"
            city : "city1",
            blacklisted : "yes"
            on_date : ISODate("2022-07-05T00:00:00Z")
        },

        ...
    ]},


]
```

I am converting all IP string data to HEX :

```
1.1.1.1 -> 0x1010101
1.2.3.4 -> 0x1020304
34.53.63.25 -> 0x22353f19
255.255.255.255 -> 0xffffffff

0001:0001:0001:0001:0001:0001:0001:0001 -> 0x10001000100010001000100010001
1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111 -> 0x11111111111111111111111111111111
2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5 -> 0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5
2345:0425:2CA1::0567:5673:23b5          -> 0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff -> 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

There will be a lot of searches by IP and it will be added/deleted/updated new data to every IP each day.

I will search ranges of ips, sort, update, delete.

What index is recommended on "ip_hex" column? I was thinking about a B-tree search on HEX not STR.

I want to have an efficient database. What other optimizations should i take into consideration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should pad the hex strings with leading "0", otherwise sort and ranges will not work properly.

Note the different formats of IPv6 addresses. Following addresses are all valid representation for the same IP

```
2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5
2345:0425:2CA1::0567:5673:23b5
2345:0425:2ca1:0:0:0567:5673:23b5
2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:567:5673:23b5
```

Ensure a consistent format, otherwise the query will be difficult.

When you talk about IP-Ranges then you mean typically IP-Subnets. In order to calculate subnets you need boolean functions like `and or not xor`. They are not available in MongoDB aggregation framework (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-55386?filter=-2), you need to process them outside.

Comment: I am not concerned about ipv6 formats, i have a lib that handles that quite good :

print(hex(int(ipaddress.ip_address('2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5'))))
#0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5

print(hex(int(ipaddress.ip_address('2345:0425:2CA1::0567:5673:23b5'))))
#0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5

print(hex(int(ipaddress.ip_address('2345:0425:2ca1:0:0:0567:5673:23b5'))))
#0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5

print(hex(int(ipaddress.ip_address('2345:0425:2CA1::0567:5673:23b5'))))
#0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5

so this would not be a problem at all

Comment: i want to know what is the best way to make queries, don't want slow 1 day query, and i know mongo is fast, but must be used clever

Comment: how mongo stores `0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5` as string? at least it keeps it ordered ... it would be sweet if i can query between `0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5` and `0x234504252ca1000000000567567323ff` for example

Comment: or should i keep separate columns for each group of characters, like for ipv4 keep ipv4_r1, ipv4_r2, ipv4_r3, ipv4_r4  .... and for ipv6: ipv6_r1 ... ipv6_r8 ?

Comment: Be careful when you convert IPv6 addresses to numbers. IPv6 has 128 bit which exceed integer. Even long data type may fail

Comment: I think $lt and $gt will work but you should take care about leading "0"

Comment: i keep data in hex but they are hex string right now, any recommendation ?