# Storing ipv4 and ipv6 in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design

I am building a database (i prefer MongoDB) that i will store over 100 mil ipv4 and ipv6 records for logging purposes. Data sample :

```
1.1.1.1 -> 0x1010101
1.2.3.4 -> 0x1020304
34.53.63.25 -> 0x22353f19
255.255.255.255 -> 0xffffffff

0001:0001:0001:0001:0001:0001:0001:0001 -> 0x10001000100010001000100010001
1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111 -> 0x11111111111111111111111111111111
2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5 -> 0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5
2345:0425:2CA1::0567:5673:23b5          -> 0x234504252ca1000000000567567323b5
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff -> 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

I will have a lot of queries retrieving data by IP. I don't care about space, queries must be as fast as possible.

I was thinking about storing in binary or have different 4 (for ipv4) and 8 columns (for ipv6) spitted IP parts.

What is the most efficient way in terms of speed to achieve that?

Comment: You asked similar question already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914790/mongodb-ipv4-ipv6-hex-index If you don't care about space (incl. space used for indexes) and if you have to query only single IP-Addresses (i.e. no ranges/subnet), then it does not really matter in which format you store the data. Put an index on the field/fields and simple use them. I don't think you will face any difference in query performance with different formats.

Comment: and keep data in string? wouldn't that start a full collection search?

Comment: Why do you think so? Did you ever check the [explain](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) plan of your query?

Comment: someone recommended me graph database, i was thinking about to make a new collection each day so i can slice database in multiple pieces